# Meteor Roles package - userIsInRole always returns false

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I want to have a filter on routing level, checking if the user is in a specific role.

```
this.route('gamePage', {
    path: '/game/:slug/',
    onBeforeAction: teamFilter,
    waitOn: function() { return […]; },
    data: function() { return Games.findOne({slug: this.params.slug}); }
});
```

Here is my filter:

```
var teamFilter = function(pause) {
    if (Meteor.user()) {
        Meteor.call('checkPermission', this.params.slug, Meteor.userId(), function(error, result) {
            if (error) {
                throwError(error.reason, error.details);
                return null;
            }
            console.log(result); // returns always false
            if (!result) {
                this.render('noAccess');
                pause();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In my collection:

```
checkPermission: function(gameSlug, userId) {
        if (serverVar) { // only executed on the server
            var game = Games.findOne({slug: gameSlug});
            if (game) {
                if (!Roles.userIsInRole(userId, game._id, ['administrator', 'team'])) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My first problem is that `Roles.userIsInRole(userId, game._id, ['administrator', 'team']` always returns false. At first, I had this code in my `router.js`, but then I thought that it does not work because of a missing publication/subscription, so I ensured that the code runs only on the server. I checked the database and the user is in the role.

My second problem is that I get an exception (`Exception in delivering result of invoking 'checkPermission': http://localhost:3000/lib/router.js?77b3b67967715e480a1ce463f3447ec61898e7d5:14:28`) at this point: `this.render('noAccess');` and I don't know why.

I already read this: [meteor Roles.userIsInRole() always returning false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250668/meteor-roles-userisinrole-always-returning-false) but it didn't solve my problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, you have declared noAccess like template?

Comment: Yes. The template `noAccess` is rendered without the Meteor.method.

Answer (score 1):

In `teamFilter` hook you call Meteor.method `checkPermission` which works **asynchronously** and OnBeforeAction expects synchronous execution ( no callbacks ). That is why you always receive false.

Another thing is that you are using `Roles.userIsInRole` incorrectly:

Should be:

```
Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, ['view-secrets','admin'], group)
```

In this case I would check roles on client side:

```
Roles.userIsInRole(userId, ['administrator', 'team'])
```

Probably you are worried about security with this solution.
I don't think you should.
What is the most important is data and data is protected by publish function which should check the roles.

Please note that all templates are accessible to client.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.
I refactored the `teamFilter` in order to check permissions on the client side. Now I don't get the exception anymore, but `Roles.userIsInRole` still returns `false`. Is it necessary to publish `Meteor.roles`?

Comment: My biggest concern is that the user has not been successfully added to the role, because `console.log(Roles.getRolesForUser(Users.findOne({username: administrator})));` right after I add the user to the role (on server-side) returns an empty set.

Comment: Have you added user to roles properly:
`Roles.addUsersToRoles(id, ["admin"])`

Comment: I am using groups, so I added the user like this: `Roles.addUsersToRoles(Users.findOne({username: administrator}), gameId, 'administrator');`.

Comment: Furthermore, the roles are stored in my users collection: "roles" : { "administrator" : [       "miDMCYhXZrxmYSpdy",    "94aj5vM7KWMeyS6uw"] }. And in my roles collection: { "name" : "miDMCYhXZrxmYSpdy", "_id" : "p3Cz3yZnbhPZWFFvF" }
{ "name" : "94aj5vM7KWMeyS6uw", "_id" : "Ti6xwTfjhkjEofrjq" }.

Comment: You are using gameId as Role ? Roles should be wrapped with Array.
`Roles.addUsersToRoles(Users.findOne({username: administrator}), [gameId], 'administrator')`

Answer (score 0):

You can add roles to the user only on server for that you can user Meteor.call({}); [check here](https://guide.meteor.com/methods.html) method from client to call method on server's main.js and you can check after this method call if the role is added in users collection using meteor mongo and db.users.find({}).pretty() and see if the roles array is added the user of that usedId then you can use Roles.userIsInRole() function anywhere on client to check loggedin users role.